# jQuery Click Not Working/Registering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I am dynamically adding a list of anchor tags into a div with the id of `join`. For some reason, my jQuery handler (is it a handler?) isn't handling the clicks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#join").click(function() {
        console.log("Clicked");
    });
});
```

"Clicked" is not appearing in my console. I have a big headache now after Googling for about 2 hours.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add your html file?

Comment: Are you including the jQuery library?

Comment: whether the element `#join` is created dynamically.. also are there multiple instances of the element `#join`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on.('click','#join',function() {
        console.log("Clicked");
    });
});
```

> **Note** :this will only detect the first instance of #join element.
>   you may want to use classes instead of id

you need to use document as the selector to detect generated elements

Comment: Is it possible to get information (such as .data("target")) using this? $(this).data("target") doesn't work.

Comment: it would. if you used classes instead of ids

Answer (score 4):

You can also try this way out, this is the most efficient way as you can have control over the click event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#join").on('click',function() {
      $('#join').off('click');
      console.log("Clicked");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a handler from a selector, the handler is added to all the elements that match the selector when the selector (and handler) are run.  If you subsequently add elements which would NOW match the selector, the handler is not automatically added.  Those elements were not present when the selector first ran.

When you add your new elements, add the click handler to those new elements at the time they are added.

It is also strongly recommended not to have multiple elements in the page with the same "id" value.  Consider using a class for an indicator of grouping.